# This Recursion in both SQL and PHP seems extraneous

Tags: sql, recursion, theory, recursive-query

Unfortunately the code is protected by my work so I cannot share it.

My coworker has produced a piece of code which is intended to select data from a relational database holding tree structures in a relational format.

An example of the tree structure is something like:

```
{
    "top_level_node": {
        "meta_info_1": "meta_info_keyword1",
        "meta_info_2": "meta_info_keyword2",
        "meta_info_3": "meta_info_keyword3",
        "meta_info_4": "unique string of data", 

        "main_container": {
            "container_attribute": "container_attribute_keyword",

            "sub_container_1": {
                "container_attribute": "container_attribute_keyword",

                "pattern_1": {
                    "pattern_property_1": "pattern_property_1_keyword",
                    "pattern_property_2": "pattern_property_2_keyword",
                    "pattern_property_3": "unique string of data"
                },

                "pattern_2": {
                    "pattern_property_1": "pattern_property_1_keyword",
                    "pattern_property_2": "pattern_property_2_keyword",
                    "pattern_property_3": "unique string of data"
                }
            },

            "pattern_3": {
                "pattern_property_1": "pattern_property_1_keyword",
                "pattern_property_2": "pattern_property_2_keyword",
                "pattern_property_3": "unique string of data"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code that my coworker has produced involves first performing a 50 line CTE recursive query which produces all of the data needed in the tree in a linear format (1 piece of data per row).

Then my coworker took that linear data in rows and walked it with a recursive PHP function to rebuild the tree structure from the data.

I have attempted to say that this is the wrong approach because:

1. The data is already in a format (relational db tables) which can be used to rebuild a tree structure via a recursive php function and simple queries to select each piece of data as you go. I argue that this is easier to read and only requires a single recursive loop.
2. This is not a time-sensitive operation, we are rebuilding a tree of data for a 'compilation process' which will happen maybe once a month. I argue that because time isn't important here the recursive CTE query provides virtually no benefits.
3. The query is extremely long and tricky to read, if somebody wants to understand what the php code is doing they must first understand the query. I argue that the recursion should be in the code and the queries should be simple and easy to understand what they are retrieving.

I argue that theoretically only a single piece of recursion is required here -- either recursive on the SQL, or recursive on the PHP. I argue that recursion in the PHP is easier to understand, and recursion in the SQL is incapable of rebuilding the tree structure without having a massive query.

Am I correct? Why/Why not? Am I wrong? Why/Why not? Does it make sense to perform a recursive query to change data from a relational format into a linear format, and then perform another recursive function to change the linear data into a tree?

Comment: Processing recursive data _without_ recursive queries very often results in many, many unnecessary queries. And many little queries processing just a few rows (or even worse: just one)  are typically slower than one query processing many rows.

Comment: Yes of course it would be much slower, but like I said this is a process which runs locally on our company servers maybe once a month to compile some data into the tree formats -- it is absolutely *not* time sensitive which is my main argument for choosing readability over the performance here.

Answer (score 1):

Your coworker has developed a technique that allows him to retrieve the data for a recursive structure in a single request. There might be sound technical reasons for that. His query is recursive because that's a reasonable technique for flattening a tree-like data structure into a table. He then builds a new tree on the other side from that table of data, again a recursive operation because it is a tree he is building.

To remove one or both of the recursions you have to answer the question "how can I write a single query that returns all of the data in a recursive structure that doesn't require flattening?"  Alternatively, you can give up the idea of a flattened list and retrieve the data for each branch (and each branch of each branch) in individual queries. I suspect his approach is much faster.

In short, you're neither correct, nor are you wrong. The "correct" approach is the one that best satisfies your software's functional and non-functional requirements (for some definition of "best"), whatever that approach may be. Trade-offs are always involved when making these kinds of decisions. To get the speed you want, you may have to sacrifice some readability, brevity and maintainability of the code. That's just how this works.

Comment: Thanks for the input, just to discuss some points you made: "how can I write a single query that returns all of the data in a recursive structure that doesn't require flattening?" Not really no... The php can be recursive and perform simple queries to select each element of data that rebuilds the tree. We aren't limited to one query and in fact I believe using a single query loses readability but gains performance in a situation where performance is not important.

Comment: Then you have your answer.